# Lg 3g saving audio file as video (android 5.1)

Tags: android, audio, recorder, lg, 3gp

Trying to save audio file in Lg g3 running android 5.1 results in saving a video file instead of an audio file. I will appreciate if someone can solve this issue for me.

```
 private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("record", "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start(); }
```

Comment: What's up with all the drive-by downvoting lately?   The poster has stated their problem, and provided code which demonstrates it.

Answer (score 0):

you can visit this links for problem, [link1](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/audio-recording-example-in-android.html)or [link2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html).

and if you want audio in actual MP3 Codec than you need to use some 3rd party lib like [link3](https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid).